# jQuery - ScrollTo - focus menu on selected target

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Is it possible to add "active" or "inactive" on a menu that uses scrollTo to indicate if the visitor have selected that menu option or not.

Like:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#target1" class="inactive">Target 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#target2" class="active">Target 2</a></li> <-- selected.
 <li><a href="target3" class="inactive">Target 3</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show the script when link is clicked

Comment: @Sibu I got a solution down below, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this i have given your ul an id menu

```
    $('#menu li a').hover(
  function () {

$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
  }, 
  function () {

    $(this).addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

[Live Demo OnHover](http://jsfiddle.net/JCW7g/)

​if you want to do it on click use this

```
    $('#menu li a').click(
  function () {

$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
      $('#menu li a').not(this).addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

​[Live Demo OnClick](http://jsfiddle.net/TZvMP/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add the `"active"` or `"inactive"` to your class when the link is clicked. On the `onclick` event of the links, you can use Jquery [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function to add the "active" class and use [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to remove the `"inactive"` class